# cmake set command syntax for static libraries

Tags: debugging, linker, cmake, release

I want to link different libraries for Debug/Release mode, in the CMakeLists.txt, I tried this first:

```
set(basic_lib 
    debug
        ws2_32 cryptlibd 
    optimized 
        ws2_32 cryptlib 
)
```

This doesn't work, it always looking for the **ws2_32+cryptlibd**, even in Release mode, which causes linking error.
Again I tried:

```
set(basic_lib 
    optimized <---------- put optimized first
        ws2_32 cryptlib 
    debug
        ws2_32 cryptlibd 
)
```

now it always linking to **ws2_32+cryptlib**, in both Release/Debug mode.

It seems that cmake links to the library which defined first.

Then I tried a simple one:

```
set(basic_lib 
    debug
        cryptlibd 
    optimized 
        cryptlib 
)
```

only one lib to link, this time everything works fine, why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html), in particular the command syntax:

> ```
> target_link_libraries(<target> [item1 [item2 [...]]]
>                       [[debug|optimized|general] <item>] ...)
> ```

Note how for each item you need to specify `debug`/`optimized`/`general` separately. This is simply how the command works.

For more fine grained control, you may use [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#introduction) to set such things.

```
set(basic_libs
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:ws2_32d.lib cryptlibd.lib>
    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:ws2_32.lib cryptlib.lib>)
target_link_libraries(foo ${basic_libs})
```

Note though that the semantics are slightly different here: You will get the `d` libraries *only* for the Debug configuration, while the specifying `debug` for `target_link_libraries` applies to all configurations listed in [`DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_gbl/DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS.html#prop_gbl:DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS).

Comment: I don't think the remark about DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS is true. However, the MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_* target properties are consumed.

Comment: @steveire _The debug keyword corresponds to the Debug configuration (or to configurations named in the DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS global property if it is set)_ From the docs of `target_link_libraries` linked above. Note that by default, `DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS` is empty and you must set it before the first call to `target_link_libraries` to have any effect. Overall, it's quite a fragile mechanism compared to generator expressions.

Comment: Ah, I inverted the meaning of your comment, sorry :). I thought you meant `DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS` applies to generator expressions.